# Firebase Unity SDK: 100% hang on iOS when the application resumes

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I just upgraded the Firebase Unity SDK to version 1.1.0 (from 1.0.1), and noticing a new critical issue. The application hangs completely when the user exits via the home button and then attempts to come back to it. The only thing in the log is the Unity messages:

-> applicationWillResignActive()
-> applicationWillEnterForeground()

This is the callstack of the Unity thread during the hang, in a development build with all debug info (gives practically no info)

[image: Callstack on the Unity thread]

I am positive this is caused by the Firebase SDK, specifically the Messaging package (I am also using the Analytics package). These are the experiments I did:

- Completely remove all firebase SDK components: Problem fixed
- Remove all firebase messaging SDK dlls and my Messaging initialization code: Problem fixed
- Keep firebase messaging SDK dlls but remove my Messaging initialization code: Problem remains

I am at a loss over how to proceed here. Even if someone can recommend an experiment to try and track it down further, it'd be appreciated.

Comment: I was having same hanging issue with Firebase Real time database but my use case was limited so i migrated to Rest APIs which they have given for Firebase DB only till they provide a decent upgrade for the same.

Comment: How did you fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. I was able to resolve this problem by set FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled=NO at info.plist.
Also you can write plist.root.SetBoolean("FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled",false) in your PostBuildScript.